# Are distributions of innovations standardized in GARCH models in `rugarch` package in R

Tags: r, distributions, garch, standardization, t-distribution

I estimates FIGARCH model using rugarch package. While model specification by the function `ugarchspec`, one of its argument is `distribution.model` that specifies the conditional density to use for the innovations. By the theory, the innovations needs to have zero mean and unit variance, so need to be standardized.

So my question is, whether setting the argument to the values `"norm"` or `"std"` corresponds to the standardized normal and standardized Student-$t$ distribution?

The R code below:

```
figarch_spec  = ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="fiGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)),
                        mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0), include.mean=FALSE),
                        distribution.model="norm")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the distributions are always standardized to have zero mean and unit variance. For details, see section *2.3. Conditional Distributions* in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) of the `rugarch` package (starting from p. 16).

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: @DominikaKollárová, you are welcome!